# I want to detect if a character has been entered by the user before enter is pressed

Tags: c++, detect, enter

I'm creating a text editor and here is its code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

int main()
{
    system("cls"); system("COLOR F0");
    std::string input;
    static int lineNo=0;
    while(true)
    {
        lineNo+=1;
        std::cout << lineNo << "\t";
        input=="{" ? std::cout << "\t" : std::cout << "";
        input=="(" ? std::cout << "\t" : std::cout << "";
        input=="[" ? std::cout << "\t" : std::cout << "";
        std::getline(std::cin, input);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I want to create an auto-completion tool for the brackets which enters the closing bracket instantly after the opening brace has been typed. Please help me as I am just a beginner.

Comment: It's not possible using standard C++, you need to use platform-specific functionality. As it seems you're on Windows I suggest you check [the console functions on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682073%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You could use getch() function from conio.h library for scanning a single character only.You can declare a character variable and scan for braces like this.

```
char in;
in=getch();
if(in=="{")
{
 //Write your code according to your uses.
}
```

Comment: Its a start, thank you but I want something like std::getline. Pls excuse me I'm only a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

`std::cin` is your program's standard input. It does not (in general) mean "the user's keyboard" or even "input to the terminal" or anything like that. How you get stuff from `cin` depends on how things are being written to your standard input, which typically does not happen character by character. Often your terminal only sends data to a program's standard input after a newline (after the user presses enter), in which case there's no way for you to get to that data beforehand through `cin`.

For what you're describing, you'll need to use (as Joachim Pileborg pointed out) platform-specific functionality, such as [PeekConsoleInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684344%28VS.85%29.aspx) on Windows. You may also find [GetAsyncKeyState](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646293%28VS.85%29.aspx) useful.

Comment: Is there anything that isn't platform independent, like in the normal c++ (mingw and g++) libraries?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean *is* platform independent. No, not in standard C++. You may want to check out a cross-platform library, like SFML.